# Execute android app in the background without activity

Tags: java, android, background-process, intentservice

I'm trying to create an application that runs a service in the second plan (background), like a service. Initially, for testing, I just implemented a code responsible for vibrating the smartphone, every 5 seconds.

Guided by the official Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), I extended the IntentService class (overriding the onHandleIntent method, as directed in the link content), and created another class by extending android.app.Application. However, it seems to me that the onCreate method of the class I extended from android.app.Application is never being invoked. See my simple test code, below:

Class that extends the Android Application class:

```
package br.com.exemplos.executarsegundoplano;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class Principal extends Application {
    private Principal() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Principal.this, Servico.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        Log.d("Background Process", "onCreate method started.");
    }
}
```

Class that extends the IntentService class:

```
package br.com.exemplos.executarsegundoplano;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class Servico extends IntentService {
    public Servico() {
        super("Servico");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final Vibrator vibrador = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Service.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            vibrador.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        else
            vibrador.vibrate(500);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException excecao) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.exemplos.executarsegundoplano">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name="br.com.exemplos.executarsegundoplano.Principal"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">

        <service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name="br.com.exemplos.executarsegundoplano.Servico">
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

What is missing so that, after this application is installed on the Android operating system (and also when the operating system is restarted), the application is executed and the onCreate method of the Principal class (which extends Application) is processed?

Comment: Is this all the code you have? Where do you handle permissions? and put some logs in `onCreate()` methods to see if they are invoked.

Comment: Yes, it's all! It's a simple code of test, how i said on post. About handle permission, the only permission that i handle is vibrate (on AndroidManifest). I need more handler for execute this simple app?

Comment: Have you tried debuggin? Does the app start? Does the service start? Are there Exceptions in the log?

Comment: Yes, i debug this app but nothing happens in log. How i say, the onCreate not firing.

Comment: Your code is OK. The problem is in starting application since it has no activity. I managed to run your code with slight change and get result using adb shell command.
Just added `<intent-filter> <action some custom action/></intent-filter>` to service body in manifest file and entered this command in adb shell:
`am startservice com.app.id/actionName`.
I hope it's helpful